# How to eager load with a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the classic Post with a has_many relationship on comments. I want to fetch all of the approved posts as well as the related comments which also have been approved. I have an approved scope in place for each but I am not sure how to enable it on the comments.

This is what I have so far which returns all the comments for approved postings. What is the best way without having to specify this condition on the has_many which will limit my use of this association for other queries.

Post.approved.includes(:comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is used in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Eager+loading+of+associations). You should use another association:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :approved_comments, :class_name => 'Comment', :conditions => ['approved = ?', true]
end

Post.includes(:approved_comments)
```